# rails get request body 0byte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I get a request.body from web service

```
            fp = File.open("/home/mm/mms/video_rest/video_mp.mp4", "wb") 
            fp.write(request.body.readline) 
            fp.close
```

but when file are create size a 0 bytes

how to view if request body are a file size or how to best way to get a video file from request body?

**UPDATE**
have a this params

```
 {"video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007febdc497da0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151007-3197-14dis8n.mp4>, @original_filename="VID_20151006_153121393.mp4", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_presentacion\"; filename=\"VID_20151006_153121393.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}
```

how to create a file on folder and change Content-Type application/octet-stream for 'video/mp4'?

im try with:

```
       fp = File.open("/home/mm/aa/video_rest/video_mp.mp4", "wb") 
        fp.write(params[:video]) 
        fp.close
```

or direct for paperclipt

```
usuario.update_attributes!(:video => params[:video])
```

result => Content type invalid

Answer (score 0):

Solved

on android http using a on params add a content type("video/mp4")

and work fine !

regards!